# How can I manage my own page with facebook graph api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a website, and the website has a running facebook page. I want to be able to post to my page from my cms.

The problem is that for getting those permissions I must approve my facebook app the they require things like a screencast of how users are going to login to my app etc.

Is there a simple way to generate an access token for my own page so I can make api calls to manage it?

Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to go through app approval if you're just using it for your own purposes. Users with admin/developer/tester roles on the app can use permissions that require review *without* a review.

Comment: But how can I generate a permanent token so I can use in my website to publish an article to my instant articles every time any admin publishes an article to the cms?

Comment: The Graph API explorer at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/ will generate page access tokens for you.

Comment: but this token will expire, I need something to generate a lifetime token so the system will keep working...

Comment: @Daniel The Facebook API allows you to extend a page access token to a long-lived one. You really should read the docs. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

Comment: I think you misunderstood my main problem... There is no facebook login on my website, and there are many admins. All I have is an app token and my facebook account authorized the app from the api explorer. I need to get an access token with my app token, and I can't do this for some reason.

Comment: @Daniel Irrelevant. You can use the API calls on that documentation link - the `GET /oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token` - to extend the short-lived access tokens the API explorer gives you. You can do this exchange *within* the API explorer. Read and understand before dismissing. This is all possible, but you can't use an app token to get access to a page.